# Programmatically enabling a custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I've developed custom keyboard on android, and I want to add a button to enable my keyboard and redirect the user to the page of virtual keyboards or to page manage keyboards so that the user can just turn on my keyboard from there, for example similar to the one in "a.i.typekeyboard", kindly see the screenshot.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just open `input method settings activity` using `Intent`.

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
this.startActivity(enableIntent);
```

Comment: thank you, that worked, what about setting it as the default keyboard?

Comment: for setting it as default i found this and it worked for me: InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();

Comment: cool Approach, thanks, No extra permission required.

Answer (score 1):

well there is two solution , 
if you want to do this fully automaized you need to get access to control the mobile keybored , if you have access you will be doing this automaticly , through this code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

other wise you can switch him to the setting keybored profile through this code

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = 
(InputMethodManager) 

getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

here is some function which can help you with your application development to deal with the keyboreds setup  :

```
**//get the old default keyboard in case you want to** 
use it later, or keep it enabled
String oldDefaultKeyboard = 
Settings.Secure.getString(resolver, 
Setting.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);

**//enable your keyboard without user permission**
Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, 
Settings.Secure.ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS, 
"com.my.keyboard/.full.path");

**//set your keyboard as the new default keyboard without user permission**
Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, 
Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD, 
"com.my.keyboard/.full.path");
```

//restore the keybored to default setting back through this code

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

```
int currentKeyboard = 0;
boolean isShifted = kv.isShifted();
for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length; i++) {
    if(kv.getKeyboard().equals(keyboard[i])){
        currentKeyboard = i;
        break;
    }
}

super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

initializeKeyboardArray();
setKeyboard(keyboard[currentKeyboard]);
kv.setShifted(isShifted);

}

private void initializeKeyboardArray(){
keyboard = new Keyboard[7];
keyboard[ARABIC] = arabic;
keyboard[ARABIC_SHIFT] = arabicShift;
keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS] = arabicSymbols;
keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = arabicSymbolsShift;
keyboard[QWERTY] = qwerty;
keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS] = qwertySymbols;
keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = qwertySymbolsShift;
}
```

Comment: thank you, what about setting it as the default keyboard, how can I redirect user to that page without gaining any extra permission.

Comment: you may use these codes , it will install the keybored on his device without gaining permission or access 

   //enable your keyboard
    Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, 
    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS, 
    "com.my.keyboard/.full.path");

    //set your keyboard as the new default keyboard
    Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, 
    Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD, 
    "com.my.keyboard/.full.path");

try it  , it will work :)

Comment: this functions need permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.and WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not available to applications. No app outside of the system/firmware can get that permisssion. Cannt I just direct the user to set the keyboard as default as in a.i.typekeybaord for example?

Comment: @KhalidALBitar alright i have edited  my answer again check the code for default keybored restore .

Comment: thank you, for setting it as default i found this and it worked for me: InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
                                enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(enableIntent);
```